# Rename file after upload based on criteria

Tags: php, rename, revision

If I upload two files with the same name in PHP, the newest one overrides the older version. To prevent this I wrote the following code. However, it seems to timeout whenever I choose Minor from the HTML selectbox. I'm thinking it has something to do with how my variable `$i` is assigned. Any ideas?

```
if ( isset( $_POST['addfile'] ) ) {

// variables
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'repository/'); 
$fileName = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];

if($_POST['rev_type'] == 'Minor') {

    function update_file_name_minor($file) 
    {
      $pos = strrpos($file,'.');
      $ext = substr($file,$pos); 
      $dir = strrpos($file,'/');
      $dr  = substr($file,0,($dir+1)); 

      $arr = explode('/',$file);
      $fName = substr($arr[(count($arr) - 1)], 0, -strlen($ext));

      $exist = FALSE;
      $i = 0.01;

      while(!$exist)
      {
        $file = $dr.$fName.'_'.'Ver '.$i.$ext;

        if(!file_exists($file))
          $exist = TRUE;

        $i + 0.01;
      }

      return $file;
    }

    // check for which action should be taken if file already exist
    if(file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $fileName['name'])) 
    {
      $updatedFileName = update_file_name_minor(UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']);
      move_uploaded_file($fileName['tmp_name'], $updatedFileName);

      echo "You have successfully uploaded and renamed the file as a minor revision.";
    }
    else
    {
      move_uploaded_file($fileName['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']);

     echo "You have successfully uploaded the file.";
    }

}

elseif($_POST['rev_type'] == 'Major') {

    function update_file_name_major($file) 
    {
      $pos = strrpos($file,'.');
      $ext = substr($file,$pos); 
      $dir = strrpos($file,'/');
      $dr  = substr($file,0,($dir+1)); 

      $arr = explode('/',$file);
      $fName = substr($arr[(count($arr) - 1)], 0, -strlen($ext));

      $exist = FALSE;
      $i = 2;

      while(!$exist)
      {
        $file = $dr.$fName.'_'.'Ver '.$i.$ext;

        if(!file_exists($file))
          $exist = TRUE;

        $i++;
      }

      return $file;
    }

    // check for which action should be taken if file already exist
    if(file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $fileName['name'])) 
    {
      $updatedFileName = update_file_name_major(UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']);
      move_uploaded_file($fileName['tmp_name'], $updatedFileName);

      echo "You have successfully uploaded and renamed the file as a major revision.";
    }
    else
    {
      move_uploaded_file($fileName['tmp_name'], UPLOAD_DIR.$fileName['name']);

     echo "You have successfully uploaded the file.";
    }           
  }         
} //main if
```

Comment: You created an endless loop. Take a look at the logic behind this: `if(!file_exists($file)) exist = TRUE;`

Comment: just add the date string to the end - this will make the file name always unique

Comment: So should I set it as false? How would I fix the loop? @arkascha

Answer (score 0):

You can rename file after upload. Like this.

```
    function random_string($length) {
           $key = '';
           $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
             $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
               }

         return $key;
            }

         $filename_tmp=random_string(8);
         $filename=$filename_tmp.".jpg";
  // $filename is autogenerated unique name with 8 Digit.

 // Then change this line:
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],"UPLOAD_DIR/".$filename);
```

Comment: You should definitely format this code, very difficult to read

Comment: I've thought about using a random number generator but the reason I would like in the above format is so I can use it as a primitive version control script for personal use. It would quickly allow me to glance and see what files have last changed.

Comment: Then you can rename file with current datetime with seconds. Then that all images are unique name. <?php $filename=date("d-m-Y H:i:s");?>

Comment: The reason for the above Version 1 or Version 0.1 instead of a random number or date time is it makes it more human readable. It takes me less than half a second to see a major and minor change with Version 1.1 then it would if I had to go to the most recent datetime file. I appreciate the help but I am firm with the above way of doing version control.

Comment: As better I understood, suppose you want to store client data with image. Then when you upload next image with same name it replace the previous image. You want to store both image? Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Would that not be possible with the method above?

Comment: Try this. Create a Database. Insert Image location. Then read last data with id. Wait. Give me time to develop your requirement. After making your required details I provide you download link. I provide you *.sql db, php code.

Comment: Hey hikaru12, your program is ready. You can download it from link  
[click here](http://www.kanhaiyainfosys.com/image_upload.zip)

Comment: I've checked it out and the pictures never seem to upload even after ensuring all the database information is set correctly. Even so, do keep in mind this program is mainly for use on code and perhaps documents. I will not be versioning images.

Answer (score 0):

`$i += 0.1` and changed `$fName = current(explode(".",end(explode("/",$file))));` to ensure the filename is correctly being set to the file location.